# Unable to authenticate on my ubuntu server wireless router

Tags: networking, network-manager, wireless-access-point, netplan

I have ubuntu 17.10 server edition installed to act as a router. Everything works just fine. The only problem I'm having is with setting up the wireless part of the router. I can see the AP on my client computers and mobile devices, but I can't authenticate. Clients keep saying there is an authentication problem.

When I don't set a password for the AP everything works just fine but then ofcourse my AP has no encryption, which I don't want. My devices get an IP and can access the LAN and WAN. I have configured the network using netplan.

This is my netplan config file

```
  network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    #wan interface
    ens17:
     dhcp4: no
     dhcp6: yes
     addresses: [192.168.1.2/24]
     gateway4: 192.168.1.1
     nameservers:
      addresses: [195.130.130.3,195.130.131.3]
    #lan interface
    ens18:
     dhcp4: no
     dhcp6: no
     addresses: [192.168.0.1/24]
    #interface for wifi bridge
    ens19:
     dhcp4: true

  wifis:
    #wifi-lan interface
    wls16:
     access-points:
      "Valhalla":
        mode: ap
        password: "ImTestingThis"

  bridges:
    #virtual bridge for wifi-ethernet connection
    br0:
      interfaces: [wls16, ens19]
      dhcp4: true
```

[Here's a screenshot of the AP showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZKIY.png) and that I'm using the correct password ;)

[Message saying it can't connect to the network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYbGC.png)

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: After you run `netplan apply` can you see anything interesting in `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: Please file a bug on Launchpad; and add the configuration generated by netplan (you can find it in /run/NetworkManager/system-connections). This may be a bug in the way we generate the configuration. You can use the 'ubuntu-bug network-manager' command to make the bug reporting easy.